# How to search specific HashTags in twitter API 1.1 using java

Tags: java, twitter, hashtag

I am using twitter API 1.1 and want to search specific hashTags in twitter. can any one help me out how to do this in java

Comment: It would help answerers if you added code demonstrating your problem and any error/stack-trace to your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, see what [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets) says about it.

The URL you should use is https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=AHashtag. Be sure you're authenticated before trying to execute the query!

**EDIT**

A java code example can be found [here](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html).

Comment: i have tried this already but getting 400 even though i m authenticated.

Comment: Did you try the java version or just the URL?